# How to make our own texture in SpriteKit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm porting code that generates a random blob-like object into a 480x480 image. It does this by blitting 32x32 8-bit indexed patches into a calloc'ed byte buffer.

I want to convert this to make the background for my SpriteKit game. Looking over the dox I'm a bit confused how to go about this. It LOOKS like I should make an image and then read that into a SKTexture and apply that to a screen-filing SKSpriteNode?

I'm hoping to have this run on both MacOS and iOS, is there a x-platform image class I should target? Is that CGImage?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific, it's not clear exactly what you want. If you are asking how to make an `SKTexture` from a collection of nodes for example -- `textureFromNode:` method of a `SKView` is what you want.

Comment: Fair point, I've expanded it a bit.